# Motor size and Kv advice for ZD550?

Tags: motor, recommendations, weight, zd550

I'm building my first drone out of the ZD550 frame. Most of the extra weight would be from a small gimbal like [this](https://www.banggood.com/FPV-3-Axis-CNC-Metal-Brushless-Gimbal-With-Controller-For-DJI-Phantom-GoPro-3-4-Only-180g-p-1030046.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN) (180g) and a gopro hero 4 (83g). What kv/size of motor would be ideal for this config, plus some extra? Some speed would also be nice :D I'm hearing around 600-900 kv, but I have no idea if that range is too vague. Also, shouldn't I be more concerned about torque? I think that's estimated through physical motor size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot variables when it comes to building your own drone, so there will be a variety of motor sizes and Kvs that will work.

I think the recommended motor size for the ZD550 is 3508 (like [this motor](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/3508-580kv-turnigy-multistar-14-pole-brushless-multi-rotor-motor-with-extra-long-leads.html)) but that doesn't mean you can't use something different, like a [2814 motor](https://www.racedayquads.com/collections/all-motors/products/iflight-xing-x2814-880kv-motor), because a 2814 is fairly similar in stator volume to a 3508. [This answer](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-do-you-figure-out-which-motors-to-use-for-your-uav/156#156) should help you figure out what motors you want. Torque is mostly related to motor size, so you shouldn't have to worry about not having enough torque with either a 3508 or 2814 motor. And these motors should easily be able to carry some extra weight with no problem.

As for Kv, the prop size greatly affects the recommended Kv. Here's a good [explanation of Kv](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-does-kv-mean-on-motors) and [how to choose the correct Kv](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/909/how-should-one-chose-the-correct-motor-kv-for-a-build). The ZD550 frame can fit 10''-15'' propellers, so I would recommend lower Kv (~600) for 15'' and higher Kv (~850) for 10''. Also, Kv will greatly depend on what battery you intend to use. Generally a higher voltage battery = lower Kv motor, and vice versa.